# Map array of objects to object type in function params

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this function definition:

```
function example<
  O extends { property: P; required: boolean },
  P extends string
>(
  arr: O[]
): {
  [P in O["property"]]: O["required"] extends true
    ? string
    : string | undefined;
};

example([
  { property: "hey", required: true },
  { property: "ho", required: false },
]);
```

Which gives this typing:

```
function example<{
    property: "hey";
    required: true;
} | {
    property: "ho";
    required: false;
}, string>(arr: ({
    property: "hey";
    required: true;
} | {
    property: "ho";
    required: false;
})[]): {
    hey: string | undefined;
    ho: string | undefined;
}
```

`required: true` should mean that the returned object definitely has the associated property, and `required: false` should mean it may or may not have it, i.e. `string | undefined`.

So `hey` should just be `string` in this scenario, as `required` is `true`.

If `required` is `true` for both of them, it types them both correctly as just `string`, but if one is `false` then it seems to widen the type for every key/value.

Is it possible to map types individually this way?

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&filetype=ts#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYCgBmBXZAY0nlWVEwA8BDAWwAcAbTAHm1FAHlKrJNkAE2igA3qAbpUDTOkgBPAFygACgG5QWAI754WQcoBGqVCxoUAvgBoOq3vyEjokdPGSJsAPgAUtmunRlLgBtAF1sAEplUVtglVA3bmCAIklpWQVk0NCglO1dfSz7AWFQF3wcTk4AflBnV3dbTmV6t0RQAB9QQkFMXDdMQTVsC2HsanpmTG9g23E0mTklUGSAC0x5ZKtNTB09QeVyzFBrOYkpRYVlNdQtnb39ZVwaJmhj09CItSA).

Comment: Do [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/w8B34m) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's spot on, thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
{
  [P in O["property"]]: O["required"] extends true
    ? string
    : string | undefined;
}
```

is that `O` will likely be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), so `O["property"]` and `O["required"]` will be separate uncorrelated unions.   If `O` is `{ property: "hey"; required: true } | { property: "ho"; required: false }`, then `O["property"]` is `"hey" | "ho"` and `O["required"]` is `true | false`, and any association between pieces of each union has been lost.

Another way to look at the problem is that the property value type of your [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) does not mention the key type parameter `P` at all, so the output cannot possibly have property value types which depend on individual keys.

---

One way to fix this is to continue to iterate `P` over `O["property"]` but then filter `O` to the proper member depending on `P` before getting the `required` property from it.  We can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter unions this way:

```
{
  [P in O["property"]]: Extract<O, { property: P }>["required"] extends true
  ? string
  : string | undefined;
};
```

That results in

```
const result = example([
  { property: "hey", required: true },
  { property: "ho", required: false },
]);
/* const result: {
  hey: string;
  ho: string | undefined;
} */
```

as desired.

---

Another way to fix this is to make use of [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), which lets you iterate the type parameter over any union whatsoever, and then change the key to be a function of each member of the union.  Like this:

```
{
  [T in O as T["property"]]: T["required"] extends true
  ? string
  : string | undefined;
};
```

So instead of iterating `P` over each `property` and then having to *find* the right `required`, we iterate `T` over each piece of `O` and then just *index* into `T` to get `property` and `required`.  That results in the same output:

```
const result = example([
  { property: "hey", required: true },
  { property: "ho", required: false },
]);
/* const result: {
  hey: string;
  ho: string | undefined;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&filetype=ts#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxAlgDwIxIN4CgkkATCeAGxACdkAzAV2HgBc0B7YJCDcGciADyEiSAPJcMzCMGJQ8SGFTYwIVZgE8AXEgAKAbiQ0AjvTQ1i2gEZs2-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)